# Executing a unix command from a php script (need to escape semicolon)

Tags: php, unix, system

I am trying to call perl script with a parameter from a php script. The argument that a perl script takes contains a semicolon.

```
eg : perlfile <string;continuedstring>
```

If I use `system("perfile <string;continuedstring>`
Unix interprets `;` differently and shows an error.

Is there a way that I can escape `;` so that unix interprets it as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume `system` takes a bourne shell command, in which case the command would your choice of

```
perlfile '<string;continuedstring>'
```

or

```
perlfile \<string\;continuedstring\>
```

You would invoke `system` as

```
system("perlfile '<string;continuedstring>'");
```

or

```
system("perlfile \\<string\\;continuedstring\\>");
```

respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your help! backslash helped!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a backslash as an escape character?

Comment: Thanks! Backslask helped!